# How do I strip non alphanumeric characters from a string and keep spaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a regex that removes all non-alphanumber characters but keeps spaces. This is to clean search input before it hits the db. Here's what I have so far:

```
@search_query = @search_query.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '')
```

Problem here is it removes all the spaces. Solutions on how to retain spaces?

Comment: I don't do Rails development, but why can't you let Rails do the sanitization?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Add spaces to the negated character group:

```
@search_query = @search_query.gsub(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '')
```

Comment: The empty space didn't work for me, so '\s' may also be an option: @search_query.gsub(/[^0-9a-z\\s]/i, '')

Comment: slightly less wordy: `@search_query.gsub!(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '')`

Comment: Just to precise, this remove all accented letters and may not be adapted to some languages.

Comment: @DavidDouglas That should be `\s` not `\\s`

Answer (score 15):

In this case I would use the bang method (gsub! instead of gsub) in order to clean the input permanently.

```
#permanently filter all non-alphanumeric characters, except _
@search_query.gsub!(/\W/,'')
```

This avoids a situation where @seach_query is used elsewhere in the code without cleaning it.

Comment: The bang version will return nil if nothing was matched. Probably not the result you'd want or expect. From the docs _"Performs the substitutions of String#gsub in place, returning str, or nil if no substitutions were performed. If no block and no replacement is given, an enumerator is returned instead."_

Comment: In his example the return value isn't used, so that's pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I would have used the inclusion approach. Rather than exclude all but numbers, I would only included numbers. E.g.

```
@search_query.scan(/[\da-z\s]/i).join
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for such case:

```
# do not replace any word characters and spaces
@search_query = @search_query.gsub(/[^\w ]/g, '')
```

Answer (score -3):

A better answer (at least in ruby) is:

```
@search_query.gsub!(/^(\w|\s*)/,'')
```

Comment: This is going to remove either (a) a single word character or (b) any number of whitespace from the beginning of the string.  Completely unrelated to the question, and therefore not an answer.

Comment: made a big mistake .. don't know what i was thinking :=(